# Acceleration in the Z direction in Earth frame regardless of orientation

Tags: sensor, accelerometer

I have acceleration readings on 3 axes from an accelerometer, I'm trying to find a way to get the acceleration in the vertical direction independent of the current orientation of the sensor. I have been trying to google and search on forums but having a hard time finding a coherent answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To subtract the acceleration that counteracts gravity, you need to know your current orientation (i.e. you need a six axis accelerometer). Then the problem reduces to subtracting a vector of length \$9.81\frac{\textrm{m}}{\textrm{s}^2}\$ in the appropriate direction (and realistically, you also need to determine the gain and offset errors for each axis sensor, but a highpass filter will probably do for most applications).

Without knowing your orientation, no solution is possible, because the problem is under-defined.

Comment: Sorry I should have worded that differently, I do know my orientation (pitch, roll, yaw), I meant I would like to get the vertical acceleration regardless of how the sensor is oriented, so for example if it's at an angle how would I transform the readings to get the vertical acceleration. Thanks

Comment: @czarsimon, apply a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

Comment: Could you provide an example in 3D? Thank you

Comment: @czarsimon, the Wikipedia page has examples in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by the theorem of pythagoras and by projection of vectors

```
a² + b² = c²
```

and

```
proj u  v = (< u.v >/< v.v >) * v
```

use 9.81 m / s² as the acceleration vector vector (if you are working with vector projection you can use vector projection - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection)

subtract the projection of the value of the angle, to the axis that you need

this way you can know in the three axes x, y and z the values for acceleration of gravity

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Mateus. Your answer seems accurate but loses some credibility due to missing capitalisation and punctuation. I encourage you to write properly as per [How to write a good answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the site help section. There's an edit link under your post.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the attitude, you can make a vector sum. What you need is a 9DOF sensor (acc, gyro, mag) and a fusion algroithm - Sebastian Madgwick. His algorith will output quaternions of attitude. You will need to rotate the acceleration vector with attitude and then extract only the z-axis component.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked, to calculate the vertical component of the acceleration in Earth frame given the orientation angles:

$$
\beta, \gamma = pitch, roll \\
z = -a_{x}sin(\beta) + a_{y}sin(\gamma)cos(\beta) + a_{z}cos(\gamma)cos(\beta)
$$